# BouncyCastle installation problems

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I'm trying to add BouncyCastle as a security provider on Windows XP Pro so I can use it to add some certs to an Android application per the instructions [here](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html). Unfortunately I can't get it to add the provider.

I've:

1. Downloaded the provider to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\`.
2. Added `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\bcprov-jdk16-146.jar` to `%CLASSPATH%`.
3. Added `security.provider.7=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` to java.security (7 being the next int in the order).

When I run:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias 0 -file mycert.crt -keystore mystore.bks -storetype BKS -providerName org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -storepass mypassword
```

I get the following error message:

```
keytool error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

I've also tried adding it dynamically:

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class BouncyCastleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); // add it
        try { // list them out
            Provider p[] = Security.getProviders();
            for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(p[i]);
                for (Enumeration<?> e = p[i].keys(); e.hasMoreElements();)
                    System.out.println("\t" + e.nextElement());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

At first I got an access error when compiling the java class, but changed it to a warning per the suggestion [here](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/09/eclipse-access-restriction-on-library.html). Now when I run the code it shows BouncyCastle in the list of providers but it doesn't stick around after the program is done.

I'm sure it must be doable, but I'm stymied over how to get this guy installed long enough to run keytool using it. Is it possible to run keytool via a java API, or could there be some step I've missed that will make the provider stick around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `-providerName` option requires a *provider name* ("BC", in this case), not a *class name*. An alternative option, `-providerClass`, does require a class name, and it is useful  when the provider isn't registered in the `java.security` file.

When you register a provider "programatically", it is only temporary. Your program must re-register its provider each time it runs. You won't be able to use this approach if your goal is to make BouncyCastle available to `keytool`.

Since you've already installed the provider (by putting the archive in `lib/ext` and listing it in `java.security`), using the `-providerName BC` option is probably the easiest solution. Alternatively, you can use the `-providerClass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` option.

By the way, you should not use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Libraries in `lib/ext` are on the class path already.

If, after correcting the options, you still get a `NoSuchProviderException` (using `-providerName`) or `ClassNotFoundException` (using `-providerClass`), verify that you are using the right copy of `keytool`. That is, when executing, specify the full path of `keytool`, rather than relying on your `PATH` variable. Make sure that the path refers to the JRE into which BouncyCastle was installed. It isn't uncommon for a system to have multiple JREs and JDKs.

Comment: Turns out I had 6 different jres/jdks installed! I inherited this PC from a previous employee and only knew about two of them. Verifying the proper path fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to award the bounty and it said I had to wait 21 hours. I guess they want to make sure there's a full day to ensure that everything is copacetic. Fear not, my paltry +250 will soon balloon your 56K even higher. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, don't forget to start command line as administrator to enter keytool commands.