# NoClassDefFoundError: BouncyCastleProvider

Tags: android, bouncycastle, android-security

I have an interesting problem on a specific Android version. So I include BouncyCastle dependency in Gradle like this:

```
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.51.0.0'
```

and initialize security provider like this:

```
import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

...
public void initializeSecurity() {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
...
```

My IDE autocompletes the code related to bouncycastle and on my Nexus 5 everything work just fine. But the problem is that on Samsung GT-I8200N the app crashes with an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Also I set up the emulator mimicking the Samsung device - API 17 ARM7-a. Same error.

Anybody had a similar problem before?

Comment: this is duplicate question [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914108/bouncycastle-installation-problems)

Comment: One more solution you can also [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134161/trouble-integrating-bouncycastle-jar)

Comment: No, this does not answer the question why the code works on one Android setup and does not on another.

Comment: what about `1.54.0.0`

Comment: Well, it's the same since the system can't resolve BouncyCastleProvider provider.

Comment: i used old `1.50.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just messed up my multidex setup. So if anyone will encounter similar problems check if multidex is set up correctly.